# Azure ARM-template Date or Time function

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm struggeling with azure ARM-templates and wanted to know if there is a way to concatenate the current date into a deployment name.

I'm looking for something like this.

```
"name" : "[concat('MYNAME',DATE('YYYY-MM-DD'))]"
```

Is there any way to do this? Or are there any plans to implement this in the future?

Comment: It's not actually available, this feature is suggested on ARM feeds : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/13599417-add-date-to-resource-group-template-functions

Comment: I will +1 that and hope that this thread will have an answer soon. :D

Answer (score 3):

Use utcNow() function to get date/time during deployment time. Note you can use it only in parameter's default value:

docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#utcnow

"parameters" : { 
   "todayUtc": { 
      "type": "string", 
      "defaultValue": "[utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')]" 
   } 
}

Answer (score 2):

Create a new parameter in your ARM template. In your powershell script that deploys the template, create a date variable like so:

```
$timestamp = get-date -Format "yyyy MM dd"
```

Then pass this to the template parameter inline with New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment like this (also, you can see the deployment name also uses a date from powershell. See [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx) for how to format the date):

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
                                   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                   -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile `
                                   -date $timestamp
```